# I cannot get the name of the node that I add in a TreeView programmatically

Tags: vb.net, treeview

Whenever I add a new node in my existing TreeView, my code can't seem to detect the name of it. Please someone explain.

All of the other data were encoded through the TreeView design before loading the form.

Please see screenshot for reference.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim newNode As TreeNode = New TreeNode(TextBox1.Text)
    TreeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode)
    transfer_dgv1()
End Sub

Private Sub transfer_dgv1()
    Dim TreeViewRW As New TreeViewrw
    TreeView1.Refresh()
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = TreeViewRW.ToTable(Me.TreeView1)
End Sub
```

This is the function I used:

```vb
Public Class TreeViewrw

    Public Function ToTable(ByVal tv As TreeView) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable("TreeNodes")
        Dim id As Integer = 1

        dt.Columns.Add("ParentID", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("NodeID", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))

        For Each pn As TreeNode In tv.Nodes
            dt.Rows.Add(0, id, pn.Name)
            Me.GetAllNodes(dt, pn, id, id)
            id += 1
        Next
        Return dt
    End Function

    Public Function FromTable(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal parent As String, ByVal node As String, ByVal name As String) As TreeNode()
        Dim tnodes As New List(Of TreeNode)()
        Dim columns As String() = New String(2) {parent, node, name}

        If dt.Columns.Contains(parent) AndAlso dt.Columns.Contains(node) AndAlso dt.Columns.Contains(name) Then
            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "[" & parent & "] = 0"
            For Each r As DataRowView In dt.DefaultView
                tnodes.Add(Me.ReadNodes(columns, r, dt))
            Next
            Return tnodes.ToArray()
        Else
            Return tnodes.ToArray()
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function ReadNodes(ByVal columns As String(), ByVal r As DataRowView, ByVal dt As DataTable) As TreeNode
        Dim cn As New TreeNode()

        cn.Name = r(columns(2)).ToString()
        cn.Text = cn.Name

        Me.GetAllNodes(columns, cn, dt, CInt(r(columns(1))))
        Return cn
    End Function

    Private Sub GetAllNodes(ByRef dt As DataTable, ByVal pn As TreeNode, ByVal parentid As Integer, ByRef id As Integer)
        For Each cn As TreeNode In pn.Nodes
            id += 1
            dt.Rows.Add(parentid, id, cn.Name)
            Me.GetAllNodes(dt, cn, id, id)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetAllNodes(ByVal columns As String(), ByRef pn As TreeNode, ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal nodeid As Integer)
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = ("[" & columns(0).ToString() & "] = ") + nodeid.ToString()

        For Each r As DataRowView In dt.DefaultView
            Dim cn As New TreeNode()

            cn.Name = r(columns(2)).ToString()
            cn.Text = cn.Name
            pn.Nodes.Add(cn)
            Me.GetAllNodes(columns, cn, dt, CInt(r(columns(1))))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmDyR.png]

Comment: I've removed the SQL tag, as this question isn't about SQL in the sense that it's used on stackoverflow

Comment: sorry about that. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem you didn't set Name property.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim newNode As TreeNode = New TreeNode(TextBox1.Text)
    newNode.Name = TextBox1.Text
    TreeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(newNode)
    transfer_dgv1()
End Sub
```

Comment: Its now working. Thank you for clarifying and answering my question. Hope you can help more person like me. Thank you.